# Problem with NGUI Unity 2D Sprite across devices

Tags: unity, ngui

I have a problem with NGUI for Unity, using the `Unity 2D Sprite` objects.

First, have this image:

[image]

And then create an `NGUI Unity 2D Sprite` object in the scene. Apply this image and you get this:

[image]

Very odd. This doesn't happen if you use an `Unity UI Image` object or a `SpriteRenderer` component. But I really need to use NGUI's `Unity 2D Sprite`.

Then I ran the scene in several devices. Some of them display the sprite correctly - but others do not. Look:

[image]

- Top-left device: iPad Mini 1: The sprite is bad.
- Top-right device: iPad Mini 3: The sprite is good.
- Bottom-left device: iPhone 5c: The sprite is bad.
- Bottom-right device: iPhone 6 plus: The sprite is good.

I fail to understand what is the problem.

Again, this doesn't happen with sprites rendered with `SpriteRenderer` or Unity's builtin UI Sprite system. However, I need to do this with NGUI.

NGUI has a "NGUI Sprite" which I believe does work. But I don't want to use that one - I need to use the "NGUI Unity 2D Sprite" option.

Any ideas?

Unity 5.0.0b20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

In the inspector, uncheck `Generate Mip Maps` and now it will work.

I do not know why did Mip Maps affect NGUI however. Either way I've reported this in their support forums.